# Calling method from own exception class catched by its base class

Tags: c++

I have two functions `a()` and `b()`, which are having own exception classes (consecutively `a_exc` and `b_exc`) that inherit from `std::logic_error`.

```
void a() { (...) throw a_exc(some_val) }
void b() { (...) throw b_exc(some_val) }

class a_exc : public std::logic_error
{
private:
  int foo;
public:
  a_exc(int val, const std::string& what_msg="Msg.")
    : std::logic_error(what_msg), foo(val) {}
  void show() { //show foo }
}

class b_exc : public std::logic_error
{
private:
  std::string bar;
public:
  a_exc(std::string val, const std::string& what_msg="Msg.")
    : std::logic_error(what_msg), bar(val) {}
  void show() { //show bar }
}
```

Let's say I have following part of code:

```
try {
  a(); 
  b(); 
}
catch (const std::logic_error& e)
{
    e.what();
    // e.show();
}
```

`catch (const std::logic_error& e)` catches both `a_exc` and `b_exc`. Of course this block cannot use `e.show()`, because catched obj is `std::logic_error`.

And here's my problem. I wonder if there is any chance to call `show()` method in `std::logic_error` catch block when catched exception was `a_exc` or `b_exc`. I know, calling `show()` is possible if I create separate catch blocks for `a_exc` and `b_exc`, but I want to call this method with using just **one** catch block. Is it possible?

Comment: What you're wishing for is templated catch, and it's as rare (= currently non-existing w/o a library faking it) as template virtuals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some thoughts on design.

Querying the type of exception within the catch block is logically no different to simply providing two catch blocks.

To be clear:

```
catch(X& x)
{
  if (dynamic_cast<Y*>(&x)) {
    // it's a Y
  }
  if (dynamic_cast<Z*>(&z)) {
    // it's a Z
  }
  else {
    // it's an X
  }
}
```

is logically the same as:

```
catch(Y& t)
{
  // it's a Y
}
catch(Z& z)
{
  // it's a Z
}
catch(X& x)
{
  // it's an X
}
```

Except that the second is clearer, more maintainable and resistant to inadvertent slicing on a subsequent copy.

The first is using "code to find code", which is always a maintenance disaster waiting to happen.

Your question raises more questions of its own:

1. Are `a_exc` and `b_exc` two *kinds of the same error*? If so, this argues for a polymorphic base class, which you can catch in preference to `std::logic_error`
2. Do you really need the `show()` method? Can you simply build the `what` string in the constructor, and pass this string to the constructor of `std::logic_error`? If this is at all possible, it is the route I would recommend. The moment you start adding special interfaces to exceptions, you pollute your entire code base with the necessity of knowing about this interface. If you're writing a library, you've now polluted every application that uses your library.
3. Assuming you do need `show`, and `a_exc` and `b_exc` really are *two kinds of the same error*, we can still avoid polymorphism. Perhaps we can shore the 'show' message as a string, and build it in the constructor. Now it's just data. No fuss, no complication.

(complete) example using polymorphic base class (`a_exc` an `b_exc` are *kinds of the same thing*)

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>

struct showable_logic_error : std::logic_error
{
    using std::logic_error::logic_error;

    virtual void show() const = 0;
};

class a_exc : public showable_logic_error
{
private:
    int foo;
public:
    a_exc(int val, const std::string& what_msg="Msg.")
    : showable_logic_error(what_msg)
    , foo(val)
    {}

    void show() const override
    {
        //show foo
    }
};

class b_exc : public showable_logic_error
{
private:
    std::string bar;
public:
    b_exc(std::string val, const std::string& what_msg="Msg.")
    : showable_logic_error(what_msg)
    , bar(val)
    {}

    void show() const override
    { //show bar
    }
};

void a() { throw a_exc(1); }
void b() { throw b_exc("b"); }

int main()
{
    try
    {
        a();
    }
    catch(showable_logic_error const& e)
    {
        e.show();
    }
}
```

complete example in which no polymorphism is required:

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

struct message_builder
{
    template<class T>
    static std::string build_what(const std::string& whatstr, T&& info)
    {
        std::ostringstream ss;
        ss << whatstr << " : " << info;
        return ss.str();
    }
};

class a_exc
: public std::logic_error
, private message_builder
{
public:
    a_exc(int val, const std::string& what_msg="Msg.")
    : std::logic_error(build_what(what_msg, val))
    {}

};

class b_exc
: public std::logic_error
, private message_builder
{
private:
    std::string bar;
public:
    b_exc(std::string val, const std::string& what_msg="Msg.")
    : std::logic_error(build_what(what_msg, std::move(val)))
    , bar(val)
    {}

};

void a() { throw a_exc(1); }
void b() { throw b_exc("b"); }

int main()
{
    try
    {
        a();
    }
    catch(std::logic_error const& e)
    {
        e.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for such comprehensive and valuable answer!

Comment: @mdjdrn1 pleasure. Thanks for appreciating it.

Answer (score 2):

You can, provided that `show()` is a `const` member function:

```
catch (const std::logic_error& e)
{
    e.what();
    if(const a_exc* a = dynamic_cast<const a_exc*>(&e))
        a->show();
    else if(const b_exc* b = dynamic_cast<const b_exc*>(&e))
        b->show();
}
```

See it [Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4df6a331fca40a62). Though, it's usually a bad idea to call other functions that may `throw` in your `catch` exception handler.

Comment: Minor detail, but `show()` isn't a const member function, so that needs dealing with as well as the fact `a_exc::show` and `b_exc::show` are unrelated.

Comment: So is it better just to have separate catch blocks for `a_exc` and `b_exc ` that call `show()` method?

Comment: @mdjdrn1, Its up to you. You could (1) create a common base class which derives from `std::logic_error` and provides the virtual member function `show()` which `a_exc` and `b_exc` should derive from and override. Or, (2) you can create multiple catch blocks like [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/016faad8c1373c2b)

Comment: There's no need to catch exceptions by const reference, so if you need to call a non-const member function then just take out all the `const`.  However the `show` function either needs to be noexcept, or be wrapped in a try..catch block when you call it. (unless you like undefined behaviour)

Answer (score 1):

You should consider creating a derived type:

```
struct show_exc : public std::logic_error
{
    virtual void show() = 0;
};

class a_exc : public show_exc
{
    int foo_;
public:
    virtual void show() override { /*...*/ };
};
```

and then use a distinguishing catch:

```
catch (const show_exc& e) {
  // ..
}
catch (const std::logic_error& e) {
  // ..
}
```

Comment: Yeah, but that's doing something completely different. (It won't catch `std::logic_error` anymore - w/o another `catch` block that OP is trying to avoid.)